# Multi-level full-text search in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, fulltext-index

When I call db.index.fulltext.queryNodes() on an index, can I run another full-text query on the result? I need to search my database on 7-8 different properties across different Labels with different search parameters for each property. How do I go about it? If I use the reduce() function or  apoc.coll.intersection  and try to get an intersection, like...

```
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("first_name", "manas~") 
YIELD node as first_names
WITH collect(first_names) as first_name_list
CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("aliases", "boncha~") 
YIELD node as aliases
WITH collect(aliases) as alias_list,first_name_list
RETURN apoc.coll.intersection(first_name_list, alias_list) AS output
LIMIT 5
```

wouldn’t that cause memory bloat?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You best use [subqueries](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/call-subquery/) if using Neo4j 4.1+ :

```
CALL {
    CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("first_name", "manas~") 
    YIELD node, score
    RETURN node, score

    UNION ALL
    CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("aliases", "boncha~") 
    YIELD node, score
    RETURN node, score
}
RETURN node, sum(score) AS totalScore
ORDER BY totalScore DESC
```

For the intersection, you can count per node how many matches they have, so if they have been matched in the two queries, it will be a count of two :

```
CALL {
    CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("first_name", "manas~") 
    YIELD node, score
    RETURN node, score

    UNION ALL
    CALL db.index.fulltext.queryNodes("aliases", "boncha~") 
    YIELD node, score
    RETURN node, score
}
WITH node, count(*) AS matches, sum(score) AS totalScore
WITH node, matches, totalScore
WHERE matches = 2
ORDER BY totalScore DESC
RETURN node, totalScore
```

Comment: Thanks Christophe. How would this work for intersection? I want all nodes with first_name ~ “Manas” AND aliases ~ “Boncha”.

Comment: @SanjaySingh I edited my answer for the intersection

Comment: Brilliant! I just added the RETURN node,totalScore (which you may have forgotten) and it works. Thanks again Cristophe!